# Nav menu not showing, css issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sass

this is a rather complex issue to explain, so I will try to be as clear a possible. I have a starter theme built by someone else, very advanced in Wordpress. I must use this starter theme. The problem is that I don't understand everything about this theme as there are many  elements that I don't know what they're use for.

Sorry, I am working locally...

Basically, I have the following problem:

I have created a menu that only appears and disappears when clicking on a burger menu button. It takes the entire screen. It works. But maybe it is part of my issue.

Then I have my regular header, which is the first screen of my website. Here I would like to have a top bar menu. But I am not managing to display this other nav menu.

So, follow me: top bar menu with burger button when opening the website, then, when clicking on the burger, full screen menu appearing, top bar menu disappearing.

So my issue is that I am not managing to make this top bar menu show on screen, although the inspector clearly indicates that it is there.

I have basically tried everything, in particular, playing with z-index. No result.

I have also tried to "display:none" in the inspector for all other elements than my nav menu, but it is still not showing

here is my html code as shown in the browser (trying to make it as clear as possible although it's scattered around several files in this f..ing starter theme).

This is the html of the first screen when arriving on the site (I know the header is in the main, but what can I do...). The burger button is still somewhere else... This theme is hard to grab.

I am really sorry that I can't make it smaller or clearer. Ask me questions if you need more precisions.

```
<button class="hamburger hamburger--collapse" type="button">
          <span class="hamburger-box">
          <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
          </span>
    </button>
  <!-- nav -->
      <div >

        <nav class="nav primary-nav" role="navigation">


<div class="menu">
      <div class="menu__items">
        <div class="menu__empty"></div>
        <ul class="menu__list">
          <div class="menu__list-col1">
            <li class="menu__list-item  "><a href="#" class="menu__link">E-sport</a></li>
            <li class="menu__list-item "><a href="#" class="menu__link">Evénements</a></li>
            <li class="menu__list-item "><a href="#" class="menu__link">Team</a></li>
            <li class="menu__list-item "><a href="#" class="menu__link">Gallerie</a></li>
          </div>
          <div class="menu__list-col2"><a href="#" class="menu__link">
            <li class="menu__list-item "><a href="#" class="menu__link">Technologies</a></li>
            <li class="menu__list-item "><a href="#" class="menu__link">Compétences</a></li>
            <li class="menu__list-item "><a href="#" class="menu__link">Partenaires</a></li>
            <li class="menu__list-item "><a href="#" class="menu__link">Status</a></li>
          </div>
        </ul>
        <div class="menu__footer">
          <p class="menu__social">Follow us <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></p>
          <ul class="menu__languages">
           <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Français</a></li> 
            <li><a class="menu__link" href="#">Anglais</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu__right">
        <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>


      </div>

</div>
    <!-- /footer-layout -->
</nav>      <!-- nav -->
        <!-- wrapper -->
        <div class="wrapper">

            <!-- header -->
            <header class="header clear" role="banner">

            </header>
            <!-- /header -->
<main>
  <header class="header-homepage">
    <nav class="top-nav">
      <div class="top-nav__logo"><a href="#"> <img src="#" alt=""></a></div>
      <ul class="top-nav__items">
        <li class="top-nav__list-item"><a href="#"> Festival</a></li>
        <li class="top-nav__list-item"><a href="#">Esport</a></li>
        <li class="top-nav__list-item"><a href="#">Technologie</a></li>
        <li class="top-nav__list-item top-nav__list-item--last"><a href="#">Compétences</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>
```

Here is the scss code for the full screen menu

```
nav{

  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
  opacity: 0;

  &.hidden{
    animation: fadeout 0.9s forwards;
  }
  &.active{
    animation: fadein 0.7s forwards;
  }
}





@keyframes fadein {
  0% { opacity: 0; 
  z-index: -2;}
  1% { z-index: 10; }
  100%   { opacity: 1;
    z-index: 10; }
}

@keyframes fadeout{
 0% { opacity: 1;
  z-index: 10; }
 99%   { z-index: 10; }
 100%   { opacity: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}
}


.menu{

  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  background-image: url('./img/dark-background.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;


  &__items{
    width:50%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;



  }


  &__list{


    padding-left: 80px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    height:80%;
    font-weight:900;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;


  }

  &__list-col1{
    width:50%
  }

  &__list-col2{
    width:50%
  }

  &__list-item{
    margin-top: 50px
  }

  &__image{
    width:50%;


  }


  &__footer{
    height:20%;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: white;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    font-size:.8em;
    font-weight:100;
   }

  &__social{
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  &__languages{
    padding-right: 40px;

  }

  &__link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
  }


  &__menu-right{
    width:50%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }



}


// awesome icons
.fab{
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #fff;
}

button.hamburger{
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 11;
 padding: 50px
}
```

here is the scss code for the homepage

```
.header-homepage {
  background-image: url('./img/dark-background2.jpeg');
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
}

.top-nav {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color:red;


  &__logo{
    width: 40%;
  }
  &__items{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 50%;
  }

  &__list-item{
    width: 25%;
    z-index: 1000;
    color: white;
  }
}

.festival {

  min-height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;

  &__text-container{
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;

  }

  &__text {
    //position: absolute;
    //top: -70px;
    position: relative;
  }

  &__image-container{
    background-color: purple;
    width: 50%;
  }
  &__image {
    //position: absolute;
    //top: 100px;
    //height: 100%;
    //width: 50%;
    background-color: purple;
  }
}

.esport {
  min-height: 50vh;
}

.technologies { 
  min-height: 50vh;
}
```

So, what I would like, is the top nav bar menu items to show on screen.

Comment: Do u have a codepen? need to visual ur issue plz..

Comment: Yes, please provide a proper [mre] somewhere we can look at this live. Could be as an executable snippet here, a jsfiddle / codepen, … I’m guessing your hamburger button to open the menu probably needs some additional JavaScript, that would still be missing then - and who knows what else (stylesheets / scripts of some framework or similar maybe.)

Comment: Sorry guys, quite new to development. You're right. Gonna try a codepen.